# Slide up, slide down animation from 0 to auto height

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to get **slide down / slide up** animation effect for div by pure css. I wrote something like that:

```
.some-class {
     overflow: hidden;
     max-height: 500px;
     transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out;
}

.some-class:focus {
     max-height: 0;
     transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

and everything is fine, but I want that max-height may be unknown. When I set `max-height: auto;` in *some-class* styles animation effect is missing. **Is it possible to animate changing height of div, if I don't know its exact height?**

Comment: Attach a working fiddle.

Comment: No, I don't think it's impossible in pure CSS. However you could set max-height to some really high value that the element will never reach, like 9999px... Pretty dirty hack, but it should work.

Comment: No. You have to know what's the height it doesn't work with auto. Maybe calc but i have never tried.